# What is an appropriate event that is triggered when a QTreeView selection is changed?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a QTreeView object in PyQT5 based on a records from a database. Each record is shown as a separate row. I am using the `clicked` event to grab the current row selection from the tree. However, I can't figure out what event is associated with a change in the selection via scrolling through the tree.

In other words, is there analogous change row selection code to the following `clicked` code:

```py
self.my_view.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
```

I have searched extensively on the web and through the QT documentation, but can't seem to find the magic incantation.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The selection doesn't change when scrolling, so it's unclear what you mean. There is a [selectionChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#selectionChanged) signal, and the tree's [selection model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) has several other signals that might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I did not realize that the selection didn't change when scrolling. I suppose the event I would like to detect might, then, be related to focus or highlight of a given row.

Comment: Do you mean highlighting from a mouse-hover? Or selection-change from navigation with arrow keys? Or what, exactly? We cannot read your mind. Please try to explain more clearly.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. In my original message, I wrote 'via scrolling through the tree'. By this, I meant a user clicks into the treeview and then uses the arrow keys to navigate through the list. As the user moves up or down in the view, an item is highlighted. I would like to be able to detect what row is being highlighted so that I can act on this item.

Comment: In that case, the links in my first comment answer your question.

Comment: Based on your input and some trial and error, I got this working via         `self.my_view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.on_focus_change)` .  Thank you.